# SUM string field TQuery - Delphi v7

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7

Delphi v7

I am trying to sum a column in a dbGrid. It should be easy, but I can't seem to get it done. The field is a string field.

The code I have created so far is:

```
Query1.Close;
Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT SUM(field) FROM "mytable"';
form1.Query1.Open;
Edit1.Text := form1.Query1.Fields[0].AsString;
```

It appears that I have to convert the data in the string field to integer. Seems like a no brainer to me, but nothing I try works. Could use a little help here:-)

Comment: Please add the table structure, some sample values and the expected result from the query.

Comment: The database is absolute database. The table for this problem is simple enough. It has four fields: Date, Description, Debit, Credit. all the fields are string fields of various character widths. The column I need to sum is the Debit field. It is a string field of 20 characters in width. The values in the debit field is currency. I need to be able to calculate the total amount of the Debit field for all records displayed. If there were three records and the Debit field contained 3.00, 5.00, and 2.00 respectively then the result should be is 10.00. The total will be displayed in a text box.

Comment: Did you execute the query on the database - direct without delphi - and did you get the expected result?

Comment: I used a buttonclick event within the program to execute the query. I get an error code saying something about lack of numerical argument.

Comment: You should test your queries direct on your database first. So this question is **not** related to delphi it is only related to **sql** or **abosulte database**. Delphi can not heal your non working sql queries

Comment: This is not a Delphi question. It's an Absolute Database SQL question. You have to have working SQL before you can use it in your Delphi components. Consult the Absolute Database documentation for supported scalar functions such as `CAST` or `CONVERT` (and in the future, if you have data you need to be able to SUM, put it in a numeric column instead of a string column and you won't have this issue).

Comment: I am not a programer. I am a Deputy Sheriff. I write simple applications to help us out with cases we are investigating. This one is no different. I simply need to sum a dbgrid column. That is why I came here. You are the experts. I don't know how to test my query directly on the database.

Comment: The Absolute database comes with a DBManager Utility. I could not find much about it. Doesn't this allow you to execute SQL separately?

Answer (score 0):

To help you out of this issue. As mentioned in the comment the solution is within the query and not in the Delphi code:

```
Query1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT SUM(VAL(field)) AS RESULT FROM "mytable"';
```

VAL (the syntax is depended on the database you use) will convert the field to a value and then will be summed.

Comment: @Robert But note that your underlying database has serious problems: a numerical value is stored in a string field. This means that theoretically anything can be in that field, and your query will fail with errors or (worse) an incorrect sum. Maybe you are lucky and the data was put in there by only one program that makes sure the numbers are properly formatted. I by any chance you are still able to change the table structure, do so.

Comment: I googled the advantage db sum(cast("field" as FLOAT)) as "Cas from "mytable"

Answer (score 0):

I googled the advantage db. You could try select sum(cast("field" as CURRENCY)) from "mytable". Will not handle a column with non numeric values. Best guess given I'm on a bus and took more than 5 minutes to answer.